# A-Frame's orbit-controls disables right click on the video

Tags: html5-video, aframe, 360-degrees

I am using A-Frame's `orbit-controls` to increase the rotation speed on my 360 degree video.

Here's the codepen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZJNrMY

The problem here is when I right click on the video/image, the right click menu does not appear. All I see is a hand on the video/image that looks like some kind of `a-grabbing` class acting as an overlay on the video.
How can I have the click functionality intact when I am using `orbit-controls`? Or is there a better/simpler way to manipulate the rotation of a video? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The orbit-controls components contains these lines:

```
onContextMenu: function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
},
```

You'll need to override that or fork the component and remove it or ask to add a property to disable that piece in order to re-enable right click context menu.